# How to regex_replace in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with data as:

```
D:\SomeFolder\File1.jpg
D:\SomeFolder\File2.jpg
D:\SomeFolder\File3.jpg
```

How do I replace the characters using a SQL query such that column is updated like this:

```
E:\DifferentFolder\File1.jpg
E:\DifferentFolder\File2.jpg
E:\DifferentFolder\File3.jpg
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I'm using snowflake

Comment: This doesn't need regex

Comment: @Kendle what can be used?

Comment: Do you specifically want to target only the folder named `SomeFolder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to match the first word use:

```
SELECT column1
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(^[^\\\\]+\\\\)([^\\\\]+)\\\\', '\\1OtherWord\\\\', 1, 1, 'e')
FROM VALUES 
    ('D:\\SomeFolder\\File1.jpg'),
    ('D:\\SomeFolder\\File2.jpg'),
    ('D:\\SAMEFolder\\File2.jpg'),
    ('D:\\SomeFolder\\File3.jpg');
```

| COLUMN1 | REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN1, '(^[^\\]+\\)([^\\]+)\\', '\1OTHERWORD\\', 1, 1, 'E') |
| --- | --- |
| D:\SomeFolder\File1.jpg | D:\OtherWord\File1.jpg |
| D:\SomeFolder\File2.jpg | D:\OtherWord\File2.jpg |
| D:\SAMEFolder\File2.jpg | D:\OtherWord\File2.jpg |
| D:\SomeFolder\File3.jpg | D:\OtherWord\File3.jpg |

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [replace](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html) function.

```
select replace(val, 'SomeFolder','DifferentFolder') from T
```

Answer (score 1):

In snowflake, you can use

```
REPLACE( <subject> , <pattern> [ , <replacement> ] )
```

So in your case

```
REPLACE(<column_name>, 'SomeFolder', 'DifferentFolder')
```

should do the trick.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html